# How do I embed Perl code in Python?

Tags: python, perl

I have a Perl script I want to embed into Python. Whenever I run Python the Perl code also should execute. Both codes are in same file. I am running from HPSA so there is no filename associated with code run.

Comment: How do you have perl and python in the same file? how does the python code get executed?

Comment: [Perl-Python polyglots](http://www.vendian.org/mncharity/dir3/multilang/file/)

Comment: As in [HP Service Activator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HP_Service_Activator)?

Answer (score 6):

Something like this?

```
from subprocess import call as sp_call

perlscript = """
    use strict;
    use warnings;

    print "EHLO world\n";
  """

exitcode = sp_call(['perl', '-e', perlscript], shell=False)
```

If you need to capture the output from the Perl script etc, look at subprocess.Popen and friends.

Comment: Whi is htis downvoted? While not containing some english text saying what is wanted is outright not doable, and external processes are the way to go, this answer is correct, since it answers the O.P.

Comment: @jsbueno please assume that if the downvoter wanted to comment, they would have; anybody else is just guessing, so the exercise is pointless

Comment: It is now 2023 and the advice to use `Popen` is by and large obsolete. Unless you need parallel processing between your Python script and the subprocess, probably try `subprocess.run`.